# Why subclassing

Tags: objective-c, subclassing

A really basic question!

I am pretty new to programming and been able to produce one app were I did not use `subclassing`. I am currently watching the latest Stanford (IOS6) lectures where `subclassing` is used. As I do this I realize that I do not understand fully why `subclassing` is so good and how I can use it to my advantage when I re-write my app to make the code better.

I have found a lot on the net of how but no really a good why explanations. I have also checked all my Objective-C books with the same result. I do understand the structure and the fact that I can share IVARs etc. but I would really like to get a full explanation of why and what I can use it for. I do apologize if this question is already asked, I did not find such question, or too basic etc.

I would really appreciate a good explanation or a pointer to where I can read about this.

Comment: ...there it is, thanks

Comment: I finally found a good answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/AddingBehaviortoaCocoaProgram/AddingBehaviorCocoa.html